# Android App - Avast Security detects as malicious

Tags: android, android-debug, android-security

I have an Android app that I have written and when my friend installs it on his phone (which has Avast Mobile Security) it prompts that the app may be malicious and asks if we want to Remove or Ignore.

The exact message is...

```
"MY APP NAME" could be dangerous.  It may harm your device.
```

What in the world could it be detecting?  My app does nothing malicious at all.  All it does it make HTTP calls back my server to get XML feeds which provide the data I need to populate the different Views.

Anyone have any clues as to what could be the trigger so I can correct it?

FYI...the App was installed directly using the .APK build from Android Studio.  Could that be what Avast is detecting?  Maybe installing from Google Play would resolve this?

Comment: Http or https?  If the first, try the second.

Comment: @GabeSechan it is 100% https.  Every single call.

Comment: Did you give your friend a debug or release build

Comment: @ataulm - it is the build that is generated using the Build->Generate Signed APK menu in Android Studio.  I'm guessing it's release APK since it uses the Keystore file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had also this problem. Avast marks non Google Play apps (installed via .apk) as malicious, because it haven't any reputation at Play Store.

So don't worry. If the app is installed via Google Play, it will not have this problem.

Take a look [here](https://forum.avast.com/index.php?topic=179031.msg1268638#msg1268638)

Answer (score 0):

Each antivirus has its own definition of virus.
I also faced this issue. Checked my app with several other antiviruses like Quickheal, Mcafee, Avast etc. Only Avast was showing this error.

Avast has a designated form to address this problem.
You can submit your apk there and their team will test your file. They will whitelist your app once they found it has no malicious content.

You can also visit this link if you want to whitelist your app from Avast.
https://www.avast.com/faq.php?article=AVKB229

https://www.avast.com/false-positive-file-form.php